# How to disable model autobinding in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have ember action in controller:

```
actions: {
        createRecord: function(){        
                var record = this.store.createRecord('record',{});
                record.save().then(function(response){
                   console.log(response);
                });
        }
```

In promise (after saving) I receive message in format like this:

```
{
  "content": "Error/success",
  "detail": "Detail"
}
```

It's look like ember data make auto-bind and crash with message:

```
Error: No model was found for 'content'
```

How I can fix this, I don't need model for `response`

Comment: if you want to create and save records, you need a model class to define the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this isn't following rest standards, there are response codes that define success/failure.  In your case, you are responding in a fashion that is telling ember data, hey, everything went a okay, and here's some data that should be loaded into the store.

If you have no control over the endpoint, then you'll need to create a custom serializer, and override the appropriate method (probably this one http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html#method_extractSave ), and rip out the erroneous json before handing it to ember data.